# Need to add hover intent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hoverintent

I'm really stuck.
Basically i'm totally new to jquery, but need to add some kind of timer on mousover so that the page doesn't get messed up if the mouse goes all over the page.
here's my script..
anyway i can easily implement it?

```
<script>
jQuery('cc').mouseover(function () {  
$("squareleft3").hide();  
$("twitter").hide();  
$("facebook").hide();  
$("squareright").hide();  
$("getintouch").hide();  
$("getintouch2").hide();  
$("getintouch3").hide();  
$("vicarimage").hide();  
$("squaredown2").hide();  
$("squareleft2").hide();  
$("one").hide();  
$("whatis").hide();  
$("squaredown").hide();  
$("whoweare").hide();  
if ($("whoweare:first").is(":hidden"))   
    if ($("squaredown:first").is(":hidden"))   
    if ($("squareleft3:first").is(":hidden")) { 
    if ($("twitter:first").is(":hidden"))  
if ($("squareright:first").is(":hidden"))  
if ($("getintouch:first").is(":hidden"))
if ($("getintouch2:first").is(":hidden")) 
if ($("getintouch3:first").is(":hidden"))
if ($("vicarimage:first").is(":hidden"))
if ($("squaredown2:first").is(":hidden"))
if ($("squareleft2:first").is(":hidden"))
if ($("one:first").is(":hidden"))
if ($("whatis:first").is(":hidden"))
jQuery('getinvolved').fadeIn(); 
jQuery('squareleft').slideToggleWidth();
} else {
$("squareleft").hide();
$("getinvolved").hide();
} } );
</script>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Good grief that is a lot to do on every mouse over.

Comment: any chance you could help? its driving me crazy.. 
The easiest way would be to function it via click rather than mouseover, so that it can clear anything out of its way in time..but i'd preferably much rather have the mouseover.

Comment: All of your selectors are wrong. (Unless you have some _really_ weird HTML)

Comment: I don't mean to be dismissive, but a good first step might be a jQuery book or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Grab a copy of [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

Link it in in your `HEAD` region.

Instead of `mouseOver()`, use `hoverIntent()`

There are various additional options to tune the timing thresholds (see documentation).

As others have pointed out, your code is all over the place. But hoverIntent does address the timing problem.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work.. 
this is clearly a horrific way of fading stuff in/out, could you give me a quick pointer on how i could do this but with hover intent?

Comment: HoverIntent only lessens the sensitivity of the mouseover, by requiring a certain number of milliseconds without movement before firing. If you want general advice on how to improve your code, that's beyond the scope of this question. But for starters, you should focus on getting a better grasp of how jQuery selectors can obviate the need for multiple conditional statements. Look at toggle(). Look into using one class for multiple elements, so that a single $('.socialbadges').toggle() replaces many if()s. And look into structuring your HTML to be more efficiently targeted by jQuery selectors.

Comment: No idea what your document looks like, but assuming a DIV with a bunch of other tags within, all with a "socialbadges" class, and with the intent of hiding and showing them as you mouse in and out, you'd want something along these lines: $('div#someContainer').hoverIntent( function() { $('.socialbadges').slideToggle() } ). Can't say more without knowing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically it looks like this..

http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/6521/screenshot20100509at154.png

Each box has that script to make it display content in the empty boxes. However, it also has to clear anything out of them first from the other boxes that might already be displaying content, hense all the hiding hiding.
Each appearing box has a css set to display:none.

Hope you can help!

Comment: I think this has gone beyond comments. You should update your original question to include all this info, and perhaps a (greatly reduced) version of the relevant HTML. I or others can then look at the question in full, and respond (or edit our answers).

Answer (score 1):

are all of `$("getintouch2").hide();` classes or ID's your referring to? is `getintouch2` a class? if so, it needs to have a period in front of it, or a hash before it if it's an id. like so: `$(".getintouch2").hide();` for class, or `$("#getintouch2").hide();` if it's an ID.

I think using `hover` instead of `mouseover` would be more what you want, and then your if statements i think are kinda messed up, if using multiple if's, you need to put && between them to link them into one, i probably said that wrong, but i'd read more jquery tutorials because the whole thing is kind of outa-wack. Best of luck, it took me awhile to learn Jquery, lots of trial and error, and lots of Stack Overflow questions.

People will usually help you with code if you use smaller pieces of code, and especially if you have a small example of what you're trying to do on http://www.jsfiddle.com 
it's so much quicker and easier to help people when they use Jsfiddle. So I would break your code down into a little example, and try to get the kinks worked out one piece at a time, if you have one `if` statement that's not working, non of the other will either, but you posted so much code that it's probably overwhelming to most people that would otherwise answer you with the correct code if you had posted it to jsfiddle or if you had made it much smaller. So work it out one piece at a time, and Stack overflow is a godsend, remember that, i've learned so much here and i've gotten so much help, people dedicate so much time to helping others, it's almost inspirational.. makes me want to help other people too.

Oh, and hoverIntent is an awesome plugin that I use often, it makes it so if the person moves their mouse across the screen, maybe from the bottom of the screen up to the navigation, it wont activate ALL of the mouseover/hover effects, they have to slow their mouse down to a certain speed in order for the effect to happen, it's perfect.